# Prolog CryptoArithmetic

Tags: prolog

I have completed the general arithmetic puzzle in Prolog. I need to know how to get all the possible solutions for each particular puzzle and put them in a separate output text file. I would appreciate any help.

```
It outputs to a text file, but I want the format to be:

puzzle([A,M]+[P,M]=[D,A,Y]).
First Solution is: [2,5] + [9,5] = [1,2,0]
There are total of NN solutions output to the file: puzzle2sol1.txt
where NN is the amount of solutions.

:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

sumhelp([],[],[],C,C,Digits,Digits).

sumhelp([D1|N1],[D2|N2],[D|N],C1,C,Digs1,Digs):-
    sumhelp(N1,N2,N,C1,C2,Digs1,Digs2),
    digits(D1,D2,C2,D,C,Digs2,Digs).

digits(D1,D2,C1,D,C,Digs1,Digs):-
    rem(D1,Digs1,Digs2),
    rem(D2,Digs2,Digs3),
    rem(D,Digs3,Digs),
    S #= D1 + D2 + C1,
    D #= S mod 10,
    C #= S // 10.

rem(A,L,L):- nonvar(A),!.

rem(A,[A|L],L).
rem(A,[B|L],[B|L1]):-
    rem(A,L,L1).
 
puzzle(A + B = C) :-
    tell('output.txt'),
    (
        sumhelp([0|A], [0|B], C, 0, 0, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],_),writeln([A + B = C]),
        fail
    ;
        told
    ).
```

Comment: Have you read the Prolog documentation for file I/O? Exactly where are you stuck regarding how to incorporate the file I/O?

Comment: Yes, I have read that. So I created a cryptoarithmetic puzzle. And each particular puzzle can have multiple solutions which you can ask for with a semicolon (;), but I want all the solutions to be listed together in an output text file. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Here's a template. You can modify it as needed for your predicate: `open('foo.txt', write, Out), (foo(X), writeln(Out, X), fail ; close(Out)).` Here, `foo(X)` can have multiple solutions for `X` and each will individually be written to the output stream. This is called a failure driven loop in Prolog. SWI Prolog has output formatting as well, which you can find in the manual.